# Migrate to angular2 RC4 routing

Tags: typescript, angular

[image]in angular2 RC2

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/', component: loginComponent},
    {path: '/login', component: loginComponent},
    {path: '/home', component: homeComponent}
])
```

and in for example homeComponent we have this

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/addTemplate', component: addTemplateComponent}
}
```

and to have some URL inside /home (we put /home/addTemplate) because addTemplate is inside homeComponent

I need to know in version RC4 how to apply tree routing

Because I have My component AppComponent and inside this AppComponent I have a Menu that I want it be show all times and inside this menu(homeComponent) I have another routing

this is my code of version RC4
AppRoute.ts

```
   import { provideRouter,RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
    import {loginComponent} from "../login/login.component";
    import {homeComponent} from "../home/home.component";
    import {HomeRoutes} from "./RouteHome";

    export const routes : RouterConfig = [
        ...HomeRoutes,
        {path: '', component: loginComponent},
        {path: 'login', component: loginComponent},
        {path: 'home', component: homeComponent}
    ];

    export const  APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
        provideRouter(routes)
    ];

    export const HomeRoutes : RouterConfig = [
        {path: 'addTemplate', component: addTemplateComponent}];
```

when I call                     `this._router.navigate(['addTemplate']);`
I get just addTemplateComponent without menu of (homeComponent)
so I need to do the someThing as I did in angular2 rc2 keep a header where I have my menu thanks advance

Answer (score 2):

This depends mostly on where you call

```
this._router.navigate(['addTemplate']);
```

Maybe you want

```
this._router.navigate(['/addTemplate']);
```

or

```
this._router.navigate(['addTemplate'], {relativeTo: route});
```

or

```
this._router.navigate(['../addTemplate'], {relativeTo: route});
```

Comment: I call addTemplate in loginTemplate where login is success !!

Comment: I tried this._router.navigate(['/home/addTemplate']);
Error: Cannot match any routes: 'home/listTemplate'(…)
it considered as a one path

Comment: I misinterpreted your routes configuration. `addTemplate` is not a child route of `home`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: How yo link between addTemplate and homeComponent in order that addTemplate become a childRouteof homeComponent

Comment: You need to configure the routes accordingly `{path: 'home', component: homeComponent, children: [{path: 'addTemplate', component: addTemplateComponent}]}`

Comment: I found this 
[
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: homeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: addTemplateComponent,
       
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]